# Get related entity id without loading it

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to list all the orders with their corresponding customer ID using Entity Framework (Code First). This should be possible without querying the Customers table since the customer ID is a FK in the Orders table. However, EF generates selects against the Orders and the Customers tables as well.

This is the entities model and the code used to query Orders:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

using (var context = new LazyLoadingEfContext())
{
    foreach (var order in context.Orders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Order {0}, Customer {1}", order.Description, order.Customer.Id);
    }
}
```

The SQL generated is the following:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Customer_Id] AS [Customer_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM  [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Customer_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Customer_Id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Id] =     
@EntityKeyValue1)',N'@EntityKeyValue1 uniqueidentifier',
@EntityKeyValue1='FF947EF3-5A3F-4A26-BDB9-039C49F559A7'
```

(plus other identical queries with different values for the parameter @EntityKeyValue1)

Is there any way to configure EF in order to retrieve related entity IDs from the "parent" object instead of loading the related entity?

BTW, I've tested the same scenario using NHibernate and only one query is executed against the Orders table:

```
SELECT this_.Id as Id1_0_, this_.Description as Descript2_1_0_, 
this_.Customer_id as Customer3_1_0_ FROM [Order] this_
```

Comment: why have you put virtual before each property in Order?

Comment: try annoting attribute Foreign Key for proper field...

Comment: @BhushanFirake virtual should be only on the Customer property (sorry about that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerID ")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

After that you should be able to get just `order.CustomerID` within your `foreach` loop, without querying Customers table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'd prefer to leave my domain model as clean as possible, adding a CustomerID property will work (actually that's what I did to avoid performance issues) but I would like to know if there is a way to avoid loading the full entity without that workaround.

Comment: I'm almost sure there isn't. Calling `order.Customer.*` (where * is any Customer property) will always result in a query against the database.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Looks like it. With `int` Ids I've seen EF infer a primary key value of a related entity from the association (without querying the other entity). With guids this seems to be different. @jrowies: exposing primitive foreign keys may feel like polluting the model, but it is often recommended in EF (see e.g. Lerman and Miller's book DbContext).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I guess I'll keep the FK properties then. :)